# LocalStorage change date in tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I have a server time, which when clicked on + increases, with a click on the minus decreases. I open first tab, then I open second tab. In second tab I change time (+ or -). In first tab the hours blinks at random. What's my mistake?

index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"></div>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var counter = 0;

    $('#plus').on('click', function (event) {
        counter++;
                localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
        update();
    });

    $('#minus').on('click', function (event) {
        counter--;
                localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'datetime.php',
            timeout: 1000,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'counter=' + counter,
            success: function (response) {
                if (localStorage.getItem('response') !== null) { 
                    $('#timer').html(localStorage.getItem('response'));
                    localStorage.setItem('response', response);
                }       
                window.setTimeout(update, 1000);  
            }
        });
    }       
    update();
});
</script>
```

datetime.php

```
<?php 
$counter = $_POST['counter'] ?? 0;
echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time() + (int)$counter * 3600);

?>
```

Comment: Do you need to post the counter to server, as you can already do this without posting.

Answer (score 0):

The function `update` on the first tab is not called, unless `#plus` or `#minus` is clicked on, and since it doesn't get called `$('#timer').html()` doesn't work which is already placed at the success callback of the axaj request.

You should add

```
$(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    update();
  },1000);
});
```

to pages to update the `#timer` unless nothing is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. https://jsfiddle.net/qfxu40ox/ I did so, but it works also( What's wrong with me here?

Comment: It does not work the way I want it. In this version jsfiddle.net/qfxu40ox  in first and second tabs the hours blinks at random

Comment: I don't know how you did make them blink on jsfiddle, as on my browser all I see is a 404 complaining about datetime.php

Comment: Please check the updates [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfxu40ox/1/). It still gives 404 on my browser but at least it is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

> In first tab the hours blinks at random. What's my mistake?

The `update()` function is scheduled to be called repeatedly at `window.setTimeout(update, 1000)`.